# Tableau Calculation

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am wondering if it's possible to merge the "completed" column with the "Paid" column. So it would show "Completed/Paid'
[image]

I tried the `IFNULL([Completed],[Paid])` but it didn't work since they are in the same column [Payment Status].

I tried `IF ZN(Completed) = 0 THEN Paid ELSE Completed END` But it says there is an error in the code.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This solved it. If you have any other code that would be useful that would be great.

Thanks!

```
IF [Payment status] in ("Completed", "Paid")

THEN "Completed/Paid"

ELSE [Payment status]

END
```